# Google Container Engine - How do I specify the level of log messages?

Tags: logging, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

When logging on [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/), how do I communicate to the [logging platform](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) which level each message corresponds to?

That is, the logging platform supports associating each message with a log level, but I don't know how to do this when writing log messages from my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the V2 API (beta), [LogSeverity](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/LogEntry#LogSeverity) should be what you're looking for. (V1 as well, possibly. Haven't checked).

Comment: Could you please post a full solution? It's not considered a good idea to rely on links in SO answers.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's only one way to get severity from your application into Cloud Logging without swapping out the default logging agent on the node (which actually isn't that hard): configure your app to log structured JSON. JSON will be automatically parsed by the logging agent, and the "severity" field will be understood by the platform if it's present.

Comment: Could you please explain how to swap out the default logging agent? :)